# How to setup SSL for customain domain github pages?

Tags: ssl, github-pages

I have github page here: [rwid-online.github.io](https://rwid-online.github.io), by default it is https.
I have already setup my DNS below:

[image: cname] which are IPs for the above github pages.
But, upon opening https://rwid.online/, it still not served using https: warning all over.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please follow the official instructions on [About custom domains and GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/about-custom-domains-and-github-pages). It is impossible to tell what you are doing wrong since you provide only incomplete information on what you did. Or maybe you did provide information on all what you did, which would then show what you've missed - like explicitly adding the domain to github pages. It is crucial that github knows up front the name used to access the site in order to get the matching certificate.

Comment: GitHub does not own your domain (but github.io), so it can serve `rwid-online.github.io` over HTTPS but cannot request certificates on your behalf for `rwid.online`. You probably should use a service such as Cloudflare where free certificates are offered.

Comment: Thank you guys. Will be back soon to this task